# Don't let Vuze use a VPN

Tags: vpn, windows-8.1, openvpn, vuze

I don't download anything illegal with Vuze (a bittorrent client) and have no need to use my VPN (which is set up on my private VPS, using OpenVPN on both the server and client) on it. How do I force vuze to not use my VPN? I only have 500GB bandwith from my host per month.

Comment: Interesting question most people would ask how to make the client does use the VPN.  By client you mean some device connecting to the server running OpenVPN?

Comment: On my computer I have the OpenVPN client, which makes all traffic go over the VPN. I want vuze to ignore the VPN settings and just use regular internet instead.

Comment: What version of the program are you using?  http://wiki.vuze.com/w/Proxies_And_VPNs

Comment: I'm using the latest stable build of vuze.

Comment: Which OS are you using on your VM?

Comment: You can bind Vuze to a specific network interface.  I have never checked if this can be used to avoid using a VPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you are using Linux, where it can be done. You will need to:

1. Create a new ethernet virtual interface (vif);
2. set-up policy based routing;
3. download a small application which **forces** vuze to bind to a specific IP address.

For sake of simplicty, we shall suppose you are on a LAN subnet 192.168.1.0/24, your router is 192.168.1.1, and you will want a new address 192.168.1.247.

You may proceed so:

```
  # ip link add link eth0 name eth0.1 type vlan id 1
  # ip addr add 192.168.1.247/24 dev eth0.1
  # ip link set dev eth0.1 up
```

This creates a virtual interface called *eth0.1*, with IP address (192.168.1.247) which you must choose amongst those allowed by your LAN, and a suitable mask.

Now we set up policy routing: let us create another routing table,

```
  # echo 200 NAME >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

where you will want to choose a name meaningful to **you**, instead of NAME. Then we configure its routing,

```
  # ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0.1 src 192.168.1.247 table NAME
```

Then we add a default gateway,

```
  # ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 table <NAME>
```

Careful, here 192.168.1.1 is the address of your router, when you are **not** connected to the VPN. 
Lastly, we introduce a rule:

```
 # ip rule add from 192.168.1.247 table NAME
```

which specifies when to apply the new routing table. We are done with routing.

Now you download the program *bind.c* from [this site](http://daniel-lange.com/archives/53-Binding-applications-to-a-specific-IP.html), you compile it and install it as follows:

```
 # gcc -nostartfiles -fpic -shared bind.c -o bind.so -ldl -D_GNU_SOURCE
 # strip bind.so
 # cp -i bind.so /usr/lib/
```

and we are now ready: this command

```
 # BIND_ADDR="192.168.1.247" LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/bind.so vuze
```

will allow you to bind vuze to the given IP address, which is routed via the newly installed routing table, without any reference to (and thus outside) the VPN.

Comment: On windows. I added that to the question. Upvoted for taking the time to write this whole thing out though.

Comment: @chipperyman573 I do not know whether this can be done in Windows: there is no such thing as policy routing, so, even after you initialize a vif, and bind vuze to it, you cannot specify a different routing table which does not include the VPN. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There's an old tool called ForceBindIP for Windows that can probably do what you're after.

It's still alive at this URL: http://old.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/

It's a console application wrapper that does some networking trickery to ensure that only traffic from a single interface is allowed to be used by a process.

Normally, you'd want to use this to force your torrent client (or whatever) to strictly use your VPN, and halt all traffic if the VPN is down. I don't see why you can't do the opposite - bind your application to your main network adapter (instead of the VPN adapter). Then all traffic should flow through your non-VPN connection.

Run the command something like this:

```
forcebindip.exe 1.2.3.4 "C:\Program Files\Vuze\Azureus.exe"
```

Where 1.2.3.4 is your IPv4 address on your network. You can find this by typing ipconfig /all from a command prompt. Or, if you disconnect your VPN briefly, just Google "my ip" and it will tell you at the top.